# How to format an HTTP PUT request?

Tags: objective-c, http, yahoo, put

I am using the Yahoo Placemaker API and would like to send a request but I am getting confused as to how to send the request. The request is composed of a URL and a document and inside the document, there are a bunch of parameters. Please see below.

```
http://wherein.yahooapis.com/v1/document  

documentContent=Sunnyvale+CA  
documentType=text/plain  
appid=my_appid
```

How do I format the URL into a request is it like so?

```
http://wherein.yahooapis.com/v1/documentContent=Sunnyvale+CA?documentType=text/plain?appid=my_appid
```

I would like to use this the Placemaker service for a Mac app written in objective-c.

Any suggestions would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. The URI and the request body are different things.

It would be helpful if you explained why you're asking. What platform/API/language are you using?

Comment: I would like to use the service for a Mac app written in objective-c.

Comment: Then you'll need an HTTP library that supports sending PUT requests (which include a request body).